# Site really small on iphone

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

So I pushed a site to http://austinenl.com however it appears that on iPhones, it appears really zoomed out. From my research, I needed to add

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;">
```

However, after adding this, I am still getting reports that the site looks bad on iphone. I can't find any other source that will give any other suggestions on what would cause this issue, so I am hoping someone here can help.

[image: iphone output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;">`, which uses a semicolon.

You could try using: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`, which uses a comma.

If have been using the second option for years now and everything has been working fine. This is the way as Apple intended it. See the [Supported Meta Tags.](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html)

**Edit:** I've checked your CSS and I've found some rules which I'm not sure where they are used for, but removing them seems to help.

```
.area-checkboxes {
  display: -webkit-flex;
}

.area-checkbox {
  min-width: 250px;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 250px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Both found in `style.css`

Comment: I have made the change and still getting users with the same output on their devices.

Comment: That was it. Unfortunately I was using it to style the "Select your Area" in the sign-up form. Now I have to figure another way to do that section.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a width of 100% to the body and get back to me

```
html,body{width:100%}
```

Comment: This has made no change for iPhone devices.